# Confirm a character in a string that is an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, indexing

For example:

I have an array of strings. I want to check if the 3rd character of the string at index 0 of the array is an "a" or not. I can use strcmp to check if the character is an a, but I don't know how to get that character.

I know in python for example I can do array[0][2] to get the 3rd character of the string at array[0], but it doesn't work when I try that in C.

How do I do this in C?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the code that you made and the problem you're having. Read carefuly the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: `array[0][2] == 'a'`

Answer (score 2):

This expression will give you the answer

```
 strlen( s[0] ) > 2 && s[0][2] == 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( array[0][2] == 'a' )
{
    do_whatever();
}
```

**Most likely you used double-quotes, but to check for a character in C you need to use single quotes.**